# Win10 Global Mute not Muting Chrome

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, audio

We have a Home Theater PC running Win10.  The global mute works fine for all apps except Chrome and MS Edge (not sure about Firefox).

For example Media Player Classic will mute, but YouTube in the browser will not.

The sound icon in the systray shows muted, but sounds still plays in Chrome.  I have to mute the sound in the Chrome tab to get the sound to stop.

Any way to force all Chrome tabs to mute when Global sound is muted?

Comment: You should verify if it effects all browsers or not, or remove that statement, one of the two.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Same behavior in MS Edge.  Firefox is not installed and the machine is busy at the moment - son is watching BattleBots.  Edited above...

Comment: According to this article, they are getting really pushy about using Edge and Bing:  https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/windows-10-s-edge-bing-default/

Answer (score 0):

looks like a known issue, there is a open source project can fix it. Try to use Ear Trumpet to control the volume for Edge, https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/releases

[image]

Comment: Pardon my skepticism, but what evidence have you given that it is a "Known Issue"?  Also, I understand that this github project may allow me to control the volume of different applications, but that does not solve the problem.  I can do that with Chrome itself.  The point is - when I use a remote control to turn on/off the global mute, it does not mute some things.